# Lowest CAS Registry Number on record

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've been looking for a while and I still can't get a straight answer. I just need to know the lowest CAS Registry Number on record and the corresponding chemical.

Comment: Why? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: It's for an organic chemistry homework assignment. I already know how to use CAS and SciFinder, but I don't think it would be possible for me to search every compound to find which one is the lowest.

Comment: Currently the CAS Registry identifies more than 81 million organic and inorganic substances and 64 million protein and DNA sequences, plus additional information about each substance. The Registry is updated with an approximate 15,000 additional new substances daily.Well are you afraid of doing it by hit and trial :-)

Comment: Look in the index of a print Aldrich catalog. They have a sequential listing of available compounds. The first one is probably the lowest CAS assigned...

Comment: I knew most of that since those were the other questions on the homework. And that's why I think it's practically impossible.

Comment: I also tried that, and the lowest I found was much higher than my current lowest. Right now I have Formaldehyde at 50-00-0

Comment: I do not have a citable resource, but to my knowledge, `50-00-0` is the first and lowest CAS RN assigned in 1965.

Comment: I find this a very strange homework assignment. What exactly are you supposed to learn or master by doing this ?

Comment: We have to familiarize ourself with CAS, SciFinder and ChemDraw to make us more well rounded for formal report research. The question I asked was, by my guess, supposed to link the check digit formula and some common group areas together, as well as learn a "fun fact."

Comment: sounds more like advertizing than educating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work at CAS and recently answered a similar question on Twitter (@CASChemistry). In fact, there are 8 pre-50-00-0 CAS Registry Numbers in our database:

- 35-66-5
- 35-67-6
- 36-51-1
- 36-88-4
- 37-71-8
- 37-82-1
- 37-87-6
- 38-26-6

So, the lowest CAS Registry Number on record is **35-66-5** for "Benzacridine, 7,​9-​dimethyl- (9CI)".

Answer (score 3):

"Carotenes" has a CAS Registry Number of 36-88-4.

If that chemical is "too vague", [Naphthol AS-BI $\beta$-D-glucuronide](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/n1875?lang=en&region=US) has a CAS Registry Number of 37-87-6

According to semi-independent source [Organic Chemist's Desk Reference 2nd ed. (2010) pg 6 sec 1.1.1.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=ahbUc5M0I5AC&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false), CAS 35-66-5 DOES seem to be the lowest, but how do we know "Benzacridine, 7,​9-​dimethyl- (9CI)" exist? Cl- and methyl- are occupying the same position at the aromatic ring.

Also "Carotenes" (CAS 36-88-4) by the name itself does not seem to exist as a single compound but a set of compounds.

Comment: Isn't 50-00-0 smaller than that?

Comment: The compound is 7,9-dimethyl-acridine.  I'm guessing that (9CI) refers to the CAS 9th collective index.